# how to set specific table colums on datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015

for starters here is the code, what i am trying to do is bring the column names from the table "Producto" (producto, nombre and preciobase) but when i do with what i posted below, it also brings the relationships between producto and menuproducto (ProductoMenuProducto), and the relationship from Producto and ProdMatP (ProductoProdMatP).

how do i get rid of those relationships that came as column names for some reason?

(image of grid: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmuZs.jpg)

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:pry01_Cocina" x:Class="pry01_Cocina.Producto"
        Title="Producto" Height="431.092" Width="760.384" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Closing="Window_Closing">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:DsCocina x:Key="dsCocina"/>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="menuViewSource" Source="{Binding Producto, Source={StaticResource dsCocina}}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource menuViewSource}">
        <DataGrid x:Name="GridMenuProducto" Margin="0,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="251" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" IsEnabled="False"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the set and appearance of DataGrid columns for your taste, by setting DataGrid **ItemsSource**:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding GridMenuProducto, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Where *GridMenuProducto* should be a collection of your entities

Also you must set DataGrid property **AutoGenerateColumns="False"** to prevent addition of columns associated with each property in entity.

And then you can bind columns to entity properties, which will looks like:

```
    <DataGrid   ItemsSource="{Binding GridMenuProducto, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            IsReadOnly="True" 
            Margin="0,22,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="251">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Producto}" Header="Producto" Width="SizeToCells" MinWidth="100" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Nombre}" Header="Nombre" Width="SizeToCells" MinWidth="100" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=PrecioBase, StringFormat={}{0:0.00}}" Header="PrecioBase" MinWidth="130" Width="SizeToCells" />
                <!-- some other columns -->
            </DataGrid.Columns>   
</DataGrid>
```

Note that with **Header** property of column definition you can set your custom name.

Comment: this allows me to place the headers, just as you said. i might have not explained well enough.

the thing is, when i do that and run the program, the database information wont appear on those columns, i assume binding path was made to bind the header with the column from the database, but it still wont load the data as it did back when i had the relationship headers..

still, thanks a lot! now i know how to do something new!